# why is the navbar not working on android phone

Tags: css

`

">/assets/icon/crospos_icon_ver_02.ico" style="width:20px">
      Crospos

">PERUSAHAAN

```
    <li><a href="<?= base_url('./Produk') ?>">PRODUK</a></li>
    
    <li><a href="">PERANGKAT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pricing">HARGA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">COBA GRATIS</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

And please provide more information, e.g. what's not working?